# How to bind two distinct datasources to a common dropdown

Tags: google-app-maker

I need to bind and refresh two distinct datasources to one single dropdown.

Datasources:

- device_info
- device_measurements

Dropdown:

- device_list

As the selected item should serve as parameter for querying the datasources, the first difficulty I encountered was that I couldn't managed to bind the dropdown's value to the two datasources.

So did what follows.

Dropdown's value is set to `@models.device_info.datasources.device_info.properties.deviceId`

Dropdown's onValueChange event is set to `loadDeviceInformationDataSources();`

loadDeviceInformation definition is

```
function loadDeviceInformationDataSources() {
  app.datasources.device_info.load();
}
```

Each datasource has a parameter called deviceId (type String) and references a query script:

- device_info's query script is `return getDeviceInformation(query);`
- device_measurements's query script is `return getDeviceMeasurements(query);`

And finally, the scripts are:

```
function getDeviceInformation(query) {
  var deviceId = query.parameters.deviceId;
  console.log('Get device information for:', deviceId);

  var deviceInfo = firestore.getDocument('devices/' + deviceId);

  var record = app.models.device_info.newRecord();
  record.name = deviceInfo.fields.name;
  record.online = deviceInfo.fields.online;
  record.type = deviceInfo.fields.type;
  record.brightness = deviceInfo.fields['state'].brightness;
  record.on = deviceInfo.fields['state'].on;

  var records = [];
  records.push(record);

  // Load measurements
  var measurementsQuery = app.models.device_measurements.newQuery();
  measurementsQuery.where = 'deviceId = :deviceId';
  measurementsQuery.parameters.deviceId = deviceId;
  measurementsQuery.run();

  return records;
}

function getDeviceMeasurements(query) {
  var deviceId = query.parameters.deviceId || 'device-01' ;
  var records = [];

  var deviceMeasurements = firestore.getDocuments('devices/' + deviceId + '/measurements');


  deviceMeasurements.map(function(measure) {
    var record = app.models.device_measurements.newRecord();
    record.timestamp = measure.fields.timestamp;
    record.intensity = measure.fields.intensity;
    records.push(record);
  });

  return records;
}
```

To display data I use one table per datasource.

The datasource device_info is correctly loaded each time I select a device in the dropdown list and the related table gets refreshed.

As to the datasource device_measurements, the datasource gets loaded each time I select a device in the dropdown (I can see that when logging to the console) BUT the related table does not get refreshed (like if the programmatic `measurementsQuery.run();` would not tell the table to refresh).

Questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Is there a better way to achieve that?

** UDPATE **
[image]

Comment: I'd like to help here but the question is confusing for me. Perhaps if you reformulate your question adding some visual aids might get me in the right direction to help you.

Comment: @Morfinismo I just uploaded a screenshot with some comments. Does this help to understand?

Comment: Sorry, I just find it too complicated to understand! Hope you find a solution to what you need.